# Should not Add the Existing Empno into the database using java and mysql

Tags: java

i am creating a simple employee payroll system leave part. I am ran into the problem with when i add the leave information for employee. all leave information will add all the employees who works on the company. when the new employee comes if i add the leave information for the new employee the leave information again add into the existing employee also.i need to add only new employee only leave information how to do the task.existing record not added again.

[image]

employee table

[image]

leave table

[image]

this is code which i tried for but no error but not working.

```
 String cas = txtcas.getValue().toString();
         String anu = txtanu.getValue().toString();
         String med = txtmed.getValue().toString();
         String year = txtyear.getText();

        try {
            int c;
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/spay","root","");
           PreparedStatement pst1 = con.prepareStatement("select empno from registation");
            ResultSet rs = pst1.executeQuery();
             String empNoValue1 = rs.getString("empno");
            PreparedStatement pst2 = con.prepareStatement("select empno from leaves");  
            String empNoValue = rs.getString("empno");
            ResultSet rs1 = pst2.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {

                if(rs1.next())

                {
                    if(empNoValue1.equals(empNoValue))
                    {

                    }



                }
                else
                {

                pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into leaves(empno,casual,annual,medical,year)values(?,?,?,?,?)");
                pst.setString(1,empNoValue); // employee no how to give 
                pst.setString(2, cas);
                pst.setString(3, anu);
                pst.setString(4, med);
                pst.setString(5, year);         
                pst.executeUpdate();
                }



           }    
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Leave Insertedddddd");
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it right you want to increase the ID values of some workers.

```
    Connection con = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    int id = 0;

    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("url", "username", "pwd");
        con.setAutoCommit(true);
        stmt = con.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT id FROM userlist ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");

        while (rs.next()) {
            id = rs.getInt("id");
        }

        id++;
        stmt.execute("INSERT INTO userlist (id) VALUES (" + String.valueOf(id) + ");");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I used postgresql so you have to change the queries a bit. The principle is getting the worker with the highest ID, increment the ID by one and rewrite the new ID with maybe other data.

I hope I could help you

Comment: Employee No auto No - i used ES001 like that . i tried your code it show the error of  java.sql.SQLException: Invalid value for getInt() - 'ES001'

Comment: Then try _getString("**your table name**")_ or what type 'ES001' is and make a function which increase this value and these are postgresql commands so you may have them changed a bit